# Serial downvoting pattern?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

I'm starting to see this more and more often (and by that I mean it's happened twice in the last month):

```
 2   3731282 (10)
 2   3731930 (10)
 2   3731256 (10)
 3   2256160 (-2)
 3   2679922 (-2)
 3   2611280 (-2)
 3   3588154 (-2)
 3   2824553 (-2)
-- 2010-09-17 rep +20
```

Might this be the result of someone trying to get a "true downvote" -- by which I mean 10 rep are cancelled? Would a pattern like this be caught by SO's validation scripts (note that several of those are old questions...)?

Answer (score 2):

As long as there enough down-votes (or indeed up-votes) in a short enough time then the vote fraud scripts will spot it.

I've not idea how many votes it is, but 5 has been bandied around, or what the time frame is.

These will not be publicised otherwise people will use the information to get round the system.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a single person, casting downvotes on many of your posts in quick succession, then yes - I'd expect that to be caught.

Comment: 5h ago I got 3 downvotes on 3 of my answers in 4 minutes... Does someone know if it is possible to see who did this? Or is it possible to report possible voting patterns?